# Capture Keypress in WPF C# Application when not in focus

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, keyboard-hook

I want to capture the PrintScreen button even if the application is minimised or not on focus at all. I've seen some snippets but none of these worked in WPF, only in Winforms. Anyone can give some code to start?

Comment: You most likely need to create global keyboard hook. Code for it is the same whether it's winforms, wpf or anything else.

Comment: You need to make calls to the 'user32.dll', it has everything you need.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the following blog post for an example of how you could implement global hot keys in a WPF application.

**Implementing global hot keys in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/03/31/implementing-global-hot-keys-in-wpf/.

A global, or system-wide, hot key is a key or a combination of keys that is associated with a particular window, which will receive messages whenever the user presses this key or key combination from anywhere in the system.

There are indeed no .NET API:s to register hot keys for your application but there is a native RegisterHotKey method that you can call from managed code using P/Invoke. Please refer to the link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called "Global Keyboard Hooks"
there is a pretty good solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: Please include some details in your answer and use the link as a reference. There are, or better to say there were, so many good answers that are no longer available as the links are broken.