# WPF application that slides from edge of screen when triggered by a button

Tags: wpf, windows-10, notification-bar

I am trying to make a WPF application that can slide from the edge of the right-most screen when you hit a button (like F8). This will be similar to the Windows Notification bar in windows 10.

I am struggling finding ways to make something similar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am able to make a window with a given height, width, and make it stick to the right side of screen and top as such:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Width = 300;
    Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

    Left = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width;
    Top = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method of the window and use a `DoubleAnimation` to animate the `Left` property. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Key == Key.F8)
    {
        double distanceToSlide = 100;
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = Left,
            To = Left - distanceToSlide,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        };

        this.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
    }
}
```

The above example slides the window 100 DIP to the left during a second. You can change the properties of `DoubleAnimation` according to your requirements obviously.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when the application is not in focus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029181/capture-keypress-in-wpf-c-sharp-application-when-not-in-focus